# Batch file to create directories and move files based on partial file names

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a bunch of files which have names like the following:

```
BS01_1234_1234.jpg
BS01_1235_6789.jpg
TP01_1234_6879.jpg
```

All kept in a local C drive folder.

I'm hoping to move these to a networked folder `\\autrsrv02\Tempdata\Justine Tennent\movetofolder` but grouped into subfolders  based on the first 9 characters of their file name, `BS01_1234`.

I have the following so far but no luck.

this code worked to move a file:

```
move /-y "C:\Users\jtennent\Documents\testbatchfile\**.jpg" "\\autrsrv02\Tempdata\Justine Tennent\movetofolder"

pause
```

but i tried this to create sub folders and move with no luck

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=*C:\Users\jtennent\Documents\testbatchfile*"
PUSHD %sourcedir%
FOR /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=_" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "*_*.jpg"'
 ) DO (  
 MD %%a_%%b 2>nul
 MOVE "%%a_%%b_%%c_%%d" .\%%a_%%b\ >nul
)
POPD
GOTO :EOF
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit**

The following groups but splits too early

```
@echo off
for %%A in (.psd *.jpg) do (
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=_" %%D in ("%%~nA") do (
        md "%%D" 2>nul
        echo Moving file %%A to folder %%D
        move "%%A" "%%D" >nul
    )
)
echo Finished
pause
```

Comment: @echo off
for %%A in (*.psd *.jpg) do (
    for /f "tokens=1* delims=_" %%D in ("%%~nA") do (
       md "%%D" 2>nul
   echo Moving file %%A to folder %%D
   move "%%A" "%%D" >nul
   ))
echo Finished
pause

Comment: groups but splits too early

Comment: I have added the information from your comments into your question, please delete them now, by clicking on the little red **X** after each of them. I will then remove this comment to keep the question tidy. Please remember that the [edit facility](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46480640/edit) is for revising and improving your question.

Answer (score 0):

Below is some *untested* example code, *(it should move the file to the new location also removing the first ten characters from the file name in the new location)*

```bat
@Echo off
Set "SrcDir=%UserProfile%\Documents\testbatchfile"
Set "DstDir=\\autrsrv02\Tempdata\Justine Tennent\movetofolder"

If Not Exist "%DstDir%\" Exit/B
If /I Not "%CD%"=="%SrcDir%" PushD "%SrcDir%" 2>Nul||Exit/B

For /F "EOL=_ Tokens=1,2* Delims=_" %%A In (
    'Where .:"????_????_*.psd" .:"????_????_*.jpg"') Do (
    If Not Exist "%DstDir%\%%A_%%B\" MD "%DstDir%\%%A_%%B"
    Echo Moving "%%A_%%B_%%C" to "%DstDir%\%%A_%%B\%%C"
    Rem Move /-Y "%%A_%%B_%%C" "%DstDir%\%%A_%%B\%%C")

Echo Finished
Pause
```

*Change the locations in lines 2 & 3 to suit your requirements. If you're happy with the output change line 12 to:*

```bat
    Move /-Y "%%A_%%B_%%C" "%DstDir%\%%A_%%B\%%C">Nul)
```

*and invoke the script again.*